# Fovis_ros depth image format error

Tags: ros, fovis, openni-launch, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm running ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to use the fovis_ros's mono_depth_odometer with a Kinect, but I'm facing the following problem:

First I tested the openni package with openni_launch enabling the depth_registration and verifying that it was publishing well both the rectified rgb and the depth images.

Then I saw there was a *[fovis_hydro_openni.launch](https://github.com/srv/fovis/tree/hydro/fovis_ros/launch)* file inside the fovis_ros folder and decided to try it, but it didn't work. I was getting the expected topics with no errors, but when I echoed them there were no messages coming from any of them; the odom → base_link tf was also not being published since the only tf was my base_link → camera (published with the static tf publisher).

I opted for making my own launch file, remapping the topics published by openni_launch to fit the requirements of fovis_ros. [Here is the launch file](https://gist.github.com/Athria/1a723ce02a96908f13dc) (for some reason it didn't show up correctly when I pasted it here directly)

But after launching that file I got a *Depth image must be in 32bit floating point format!* error, [here](https://gist.github.com/Athria/c4d1edd48b14732c770e) is the complete log.

I verified the documentation from openni_launch and the rgbd_launch and from what it says I think that the *depth_registered*/ *sw_registered*/ *image_rect_raw* topic is publishing the required rectify messages, since it calls depth_processing which converts uint16 to float.

The reason I'm using the sw_registered topic is because there is no rectified depth image topic under depth_register, there's only /camera/depth_registered/image_raw. Maybe I could use depth_image_proc on that topic, but openni_launch already uses the depth_processing, so it didn't seem logic.

Also, the fovis_ros package is still not publishing the expected tf, but maybe it's normal since I'm getting the depth image's error.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206888/fovis_ros-depth-image-format-error/) by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-07-10**:
Hi，Irene. I run ROS indigo in ubuntu 1404 LTS. And I get a similar problem. If you have solve this problem. Could you help me? [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/213333/fovis_ros-using-freenect_launch-has-depth-image-format-error/)
Thanks first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Athria,

if there's no depth, there won't be odometry, thus no tf. The driver expects depth registered images to work.
In the launchfile for hydro and fovis, openni is missing. Provided that openni publishes to this topic below, it should work

```
$(arg camera)/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
```

check that you are running openni, and that you rectify the images. Check that the topic I just wrote has something. Then run the launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0